# How to convert TabularDataset or a pandas dataframe to a FileDataset using azure ml python sdk v2?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azure-ml-pipelines

I've written a webscraping script to extract a web table in a dataframe format which I have converted into a `TabularDataset` using `Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe()` to store in the default datastore.

I want to pass this webscraped table as a `side_input` to `ParallelRunStep()` in a batch inferencing pipeline but in order to achieve that, the `side_input` should be in `FileDataset` type.

The established way that has worked so far to convert `TabularDataset` into `FileDataset` was using

```
side_input = Dataset.File.from_files(path="/path/to/file/on/datastore")
```

The above method worked for uploaded csv files in the datastore. But thing with registering a pandas dataframe in the datastore is that with each run of the webscraping script occurs a registration of pandas dataframe in the datastore to convert it into a `TabularDataset` and the relative path in the datastore changes.

Hardcoding the relative path works but since the web table data changes periodically, I want the latest data from the web table to be used aas a `side_input`

My questions:

- how to convert pandas dataframe into `FileDataset` eg: to_FileDataset if it even exists?
- how to convert `TabularDatset` into `FileDataset`?
- if there is any way to find the relative path of the registered tabular dataset in the datastore using azureml python sdk v2?

side note: the metadata of tabular dataset shows a json info something like this

```
>>> tabular_ds
{
  "source": [("default_datastore", "relative/path/to/the/tabular/dataset")],
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I was wondering if I can extract the `source` key from this like I can extract the `ws.name` after initializing `ws = Workspace.from_config()` . Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to convert a `TabularDataset` into a `FileDataset`, is by using [to_csv_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.tabular_dataset.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-data-tabular-dataset-tabulardataset-to-csv-files) method which returns a `FileDataset object` from  `TabularDataset object`.

[image]

This will support all the relevant methods of `FileDataset Object`.

Comment: One follow up question, how to convert the FileDataset back to a pandas dataframe in batch inferencing environment like I discussed in my post?